# Check if File in Gzip is Xml in JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, file, content-type, apache-tika

How to check in java if the file in the GZip Archive is a XML file ? Because I try this but got the errors :

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream.get(TikaInputStream.java:265)

```
public static boolean presenceFichierXmlDansArchiveGzip (final File fichier)  {

    try (final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fichier);
         final GzipCompressorInputStream gzIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(fis);
         final TarArchiveInputStream tais = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzIn)) {
        for (TarArchiveEntry tae = tais.getNextTarEntry(); tae != null; tae = tais.getNextTarEntry()) {
            if (tae.isFile()) {
                Tika tika = new Tika();
                String contentType = tika.detect(tae.getFile());
                System.out.println("contentType : "+ contentType + ",Name :"+tae.getName());
                if (!StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(contentType, FICHIER_XML)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            }

        }
    catch (IOException e){
        LOGGER.error("Erreur lors de l'appel de la fonction presenceFichierXmlDansArchiveGzip " + e);
    }


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to look at the file contents? Cannot check just the file name extension?

Comment: Yes. Because the files in my gzip is without extension

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? If not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: The same errors. I don't know why tae.getFile() is null because when I make tae.getSize(), it return me : 5600.